# What advantages or disadvantages would best replicate a video game style inventory in an otherwise Modern setting?

Tags: gurps-4e

What advantages or disadvantages would best replicate a video game style inventory in an otherwise Modern setting? I'm looking for guidance, as it seems to veer into the really expensive with cosmic advantages. Am I missing some lower key lower power possibilities?

The background is a modern setting with minor super powers which have a power level that do not exceed the level of influence on the world based on commonly available tech to a middle class family's income base. Thus, things like guns & rifles (ranged attack powers), fireworks (explosive powers), hydraulic jacks (strength powers), man-portable tank of liquid nitrogen (freezing powers), and so forth are some examples of the limits on powers.

One of the proposed powers is an Inventory ability. Just that, nothing else. Store it, leave it, remove it. Thus, the analog tech would be a backpack or similar. Except that it is not visible or touchable by others.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I'm not sure I understand the setting. It's "a modern setting with minor super powers." What does a PC's gear have to do with this? Is a PC's "inventory" supposed to represent the PC's available superpowers? Or is each PC's inventory a separate unique feature of their character—like sort of a contemporary version of the *Boderlands* video game franchise, I guess, where folks have superpowers *and* a magical backpack? No matter what, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: The comparisons to weapons and science effects are given to show examples of how powerful the super powers can become. So if you use a middle class family income, your super powers can't be more powerful than the tech you could buy.

Comment: I get that a PC's superpowers can't be more powerful than (relatively) common household items. I'm on board and that's interesting. What I don't get is how the magical inventory is a factor. Is that a wholly separate thing from a PC's superpowers?

Comment: What video game exactly? They have a myriad of approaches to inventory.

Comment: @Mołot That is a good point, but I was trying to avoid specifying the video game, as I wanted to keep it generic, pun intended.

Answer (score 4):

To stow items away, making them invisible and inaccessible to anyone else, you buy Payload, as per p. B74, with Cosmic, +50%. Spending 10 character points gets you your Basic Lift worth of Payload, adding 50% to the cost brings it up to 15 points.

If you have ST 12, your Basic Lift is 29lb, which is enough for a fair bit of concealed equipment. Note that this still counts as weight you're carrying, which seems to fit with your backpack analogy.

Answer (score 2):

For a gear carrying ability, there are two principle advantages to consider.

#### Payload

This advantage is closest to what you've asked for. It lets you carry part of your encumbrance in a separate place. It scales with the character's own ST, which is fairly normal for video game inventories. You'll need to tweak it a bit to make it feel more like a backpack.

#### Gizmos

This advantage is an alternative choice. It doesn't really give you a backpack but can be used to give a different play style since it requires less bookkeeping. A player could even take both, though the gizmos wouldn't be able to interact with anything in the payload.

---

A final note since you talk about expensive cosmic advantages. It sounds like these are being used as your first choice, which is certainly up to you and whatever setting you're designing. Still, most abilities that can be created will be similar enough to gear that cosmic shouldn't be needed. The payload ability you're looking for will need a touch of cosmic to get it working correctly, but many of the other effects you mention wouldn't. But that is drifting off topic into the realm of setting design.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a realistic game and world where there are some surreal super-heroes who appear and for some reason have super-powers that warp reality the way video game characters do, then some of those (like the ability to have a huge arsenal immediately available with no encumbrance, or the ability to ignore non-fatal wounds and heal in a matter of seconds, or instantly by "just finding power-ups" in crates everywhere) would be fairly Cosmic.

However if you want a video-game-like GURPS game, where the PCs just get those sorts of things because that's how the game universe works, then you can just define those as part of the rules for the game, not by listing them as abilities of specific characters.